# couchbase I/O thread not getting cleaned

Tags: java, tomcat, couchbase

It seems couchbase I/O threads are not cleaned on Tomcat restart . I see the following every time Tomcat restarts.

```
cb-io-1-7 2015-04-10 12:00:40 ERROR ResourceLeakDetector:176 - LEAK: ByteBuf.release() was not called before it's garbage-collected. Enable advanced leak reporting to find out where the leak occurred. To enable advanced leak reporting, specify the JVM option '-Dcom.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.leakDetectionLevel=advanced' or call ResourceLeakDetector.setLevel()
cb-io-1-6 2015-04-10 16:15:25 ERROR ResourceLeakDetector:176 - LEAK: ByteBuf.release() was not called before it's garbage-collected. Enable advanced leak reporting to find out where the leak occurred. To enable advanced leak reporting, specify the JVM option '-Dcom.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.leakDetectionLevel=advanced' or call ResourceLeakDetector.setLevel()
cb-io-1-7 2015-04-10 22:38:41 ERROR ResourceLeakDetector:176 - LEAK: ByteBuf.release() was not called before it's garbage-collected. Enable advanced leak reporting to find out where the leak occurred. To enable advanced leak reporting, specify the JVM option '-Dcom.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.leakDetectionLevel=advanced' or call ResourceLeakDetector.setLevel()
cb-io-1-8 2015-04-11 04:24:26 ERROR ResourceLeakDetector:176 - LEAK: ByteBuf.release() was not called before it's garbage-collected. Enable advanced leak reporting to find out where the leak occurred. To enable advanced leak reporting, specify the JVM option '-Dcom.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.leakDetectionLevel=advanced' or call ResourceLeakDetector.setLevel()
cb-io-1-3 2015-04-11 12:12:08 ERROR ResourceLeakDetector:176 - LEAK: ByteBuf.release() was not called before it's garbage-collected. Enable advanced leak reporting to find out where the leak occurred. To enable advanced leak reporting, specify the JVM option '-Dcom.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.leakDetectionLevel=advanced' or call ResourceLeakDetector.setLevel()
cb-io-1-1 2015-04-11 14:31:22 ERROR ResourceLeakDetector:176 - LEAK: ByteBuf.release() was not called before it's garbage-collected. Enable advanced leak reporting to find out where the leak occurred. To enable advanced leak reporting, specify the JVM option '-Dcom.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.leakDetectionLevel=advanced' or call ResourceLeakDetector.setLevel()
```

Using Couchbase Java SDK: 2.1.0 and Tomcat: 7.

Comment: which version of the Java SDK are you using? I know it's 2.x generation but need the exact version

Comment: Its 2.1.0 and tomcat version is 7

Comment: 2.1.1 and 2.1.2 both fixed bugs related to these leaks, you should try 2.1.2 I think

Comment: Thank you . I will try 2.1.2 but in general have seen memory leak issue with couchbase 2.1.x something to do with bytebuffer because it uses memory outside heap memory.

Comment: I had a similar issue on a high-throughput web service with couchbase backend. The aforementioned fix seems to be JCBC-713; I am going to try 2.1.2 tomorrow. thanks!

Comment: 2.1.2 seems better and has resolved the issue